# Add Custom Green BAR MSG with EV SSL

Tags: linux, security, browser, ssl

I am interested in purchasing a SSL/TSL certificate for my website and I would like to know which retailer allows me to add my custom message in the green address bar like in this image :

[image]

You can see there : "COMPANIA NATIONALA DE TRANSPORTURI AERIENE ..."

I want something like that too.

Comment: Try serverfault, link is in the footer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a custom message. It is the name of your organization as confirmed by the CA.